# Ionic (React) IonIcon - Unable to align to the center

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to align the icon to the center in Ionic (React). But the icon sticks to the left as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Issue Screenshot]

TSX code:

```
type WalletBtnProps = {
  icon: { ios: string; md: string };
  label: string;
};

class WalletBtn extends React.Component<WalletBtnProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wallet-button ion-text-center">
        <IonIcon icon={this.props.icon} />
        <IonLabel>{this.props.label}</IonLabel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.wallet-button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(190, 164, 164, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.wallet-button * {
  display: block !important;
}
.wallet-button ion-icon {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the icon class add these css :

```
width:100%;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

And these should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ion-tab-button`, which automatically centers and places the label below the icon.

```html
<div className="wallet-button">
  <IonTabButton>
    <IonIcon icon={this.props.icon} />
    <IonLabel>{this.props.label}</IonLabel>
  </IonTabButton>
</div>
```

```css
.wallet-button {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(190, 164, 164, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```